# Comparing lists element by element with NA and NULL

Tags: r

I am looking for some clean way to implement this operation. Say, I have a list as following:

```
gate_entry <- list(gate1 = "Andy",
                       gate2 = "Bob",
                       gate3 = "Chad",
                       gate4 = NA,
                       gate5 = " Dan",
                       gate6 = NA,
                       gate7 = NULL)
```

`NA` and `NULL` occurrences are possible and beyond my code's control.

Somewhere else in my codes, I register a list of the same length as `gate_entry` as following:

```
amount_carry <- list(10, 20, 15, NULL, NA, NA, NA)
```

For each element in `gate_entry` that is a non-empty string , I want to check if the corresponding element in `amount_carry` is numeric. If there is at least one occurrence where this condition is not true, return `FALSE`. Just like the elements in `gate_entry`, the elements in `amount_carry` could be `NA` or `NULL`.
In this case, I expect element 1, 2, 3 and 5 in `amount_carry` to be numeric (and return `TRUE`). But since element 5 is `NA`, this operation should return `FALSE`.

Comment: You could use `mapply` here to check element-wise.

Comment: @MrFlick Both of these lists are generated by appending elsewhere. So it is possible that one element being appended is NULL.

Comment: @DarrenTsai  What if I convert ```amount_carry``` to list instead of vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a helper function to test for non-null, non-missing values

```
is_present <- function(x) !is.null(x) && !is.na(x)
```

We can test all the `gate_entry` and `amount_carry` values with

```
gate_ok <- sapply(gate_entry, is_present)
amount_ok <- sapply(amount_carry, is_present)
```

Now the only values that aren't allowed are when `gate_ok` is true but `amount_ok` is not so we just need to make sure there aren't any of those.

```
!any(gate_ok & !amount_ok)
# [1] FALSE
```